# will socket async operation ever complete synchronously?

Tags: windows, sockets, asynchronous, asyncsocket, overlapped-io

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156932 there are conditions under which an asynchronous Disk IO operation may complete synchronously. Is this only applicable to Disk IO or can similar conditions apply to Network IO?

UPDATE:
i've tested this now with the debugger and have verified that 
1) if there is data in the receive buffer the operation will complete synchronously
2) the IOCP will fire a callback regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, if for example you're reading data that is already present in the socket receive buffer. The real question is what difference would it make to you?

Comment: i am using IOCompletionPort with a worker thread pool, so i want to know if i can rely on a callback happening to do my processing or weather i should handle the processing immediately

Comment: Why? The callback will be called. Let it happen.

Comment: even if ReadFile return true?

Comment: even **before** ReadFile returns true. That's why the case is named "synchronously".